# Heterogeneous Computing Using CPU, GPU , and ARM CPU

Tags: arm, opencl, gpu, pyopencl

In my opencl application I have a controlling application part, a graphics application part and some serial application part, as shown below:

[image]

All these applications are running in parallel.

So far I have written applications that run simultaneously on CPU and GPU. Is there a way I can use ARM together with CPU(Intel) and GPU (ATI) in parallel as shown in the picture above?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can use OpenCL to dispatch work to the ARM processor or something else? Also, I am not sure I understand your diagram - the OpenCL application fundamentally runs on the host CPU and dispatches work to the GPU via the OpenCL API. It isn't somehow independent, is it?

Comment: Yes you are right in saying that CPU dispatches work to GPU. Can the CPU dispatch work simultaneously to GPU and ARM processor  ?

Comment: Again, do you mean via the OpenCL API?

Comment: Yes Via OpenCL API. Also I have edited the figure.

Comment: If you have an OpenCL driver and ICD for your ARM device, then obviously yes.

Comment: But Can  multiple OpenCL platforms (one for ATI GPU, another for ARM )work simultaneously?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11821/discussion-between-gpuguy-and-talonmies)